# Unity not working collider in race game lap logic

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am making a racing game and I have created points 'round the map that you must pass in order to finish a lap.

Sadly, when the player passes the first part it doesn't indicate it and so it can't pass through the other one.

I am using `OnCollisionEnter()` but IsTrigger is activated on those points so that they have no collision.

I even added `Debug.Log("");` to check if it actually does something but it **wont show anything in the console**. Here is the collision code in the car:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(col: Collision) {
  ... never gets to here
}
```

**Note: Don't tell me to switch to C# because *JavaScript(UnityScript)* is being remove, I am well aware of that.**

Comment: Unityscript is deprecated from Unity and being removed, you must change to c#. (Fortunately it is much easier to use.)

Comment: Joe Blow I suggest you read my whole question before saying that on every one I post. I know 'bout that just don't have the time to learn C#

Comment: It is automatically generated.  By the way, Unityscript is deprecated from Unity and being removed, you must change to c#. (Fortunately it is much easier to use.)

Comment: BTW it's very difficult to program race logic !!

Comment: yea I know but this project is polishing my skills in a number of ways and I don't want to cancel it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your basic problem is you should be using

```
void OnTriggerEnter
```

instead of the OnCollision calls.

It is a situation where this annoying thing...

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

will solve your problem. Scroll down to:

## "Collision action matrix"

You have to familiarize yourself with that, to use Unity. It's a pain.

To get an answer on SO, for specific cases of this type of problem, you need to provide the answers these eight questions:

on the "CAR"

rigidbody? / kinematic on or off? / collider ? / trigger on or off?

on the "WALL"

rigidbody? / kinematic on or off? / collider ? / trigger on or off?

Comment: Nothing happens. It's like there is no collider. I'll make a video and show you but nothing happens.

Comment: Joe Blow ok now I know. The car has a rigidbody. It isn't kinematic. It has a collider, 2 of them actually. One is for keeping it off the ground because It's a floating car. It isn't trigger. The wall has a rigidbody but it doesn't work with or without it. It isn't kinematic it has a collider and trigger is on

Comment: Well I can't  use OnTrigger because I've tried and I'd have to make a script for each one. Keep in mind that it did work at one point but no fully. Once you'd get to the finish line on the first lap you would get +1 lap but then an error would show that it can't change fpA because it is not static and I had the finish line triggered from the Race script so I made fpA static and it didn't work but then I put it so that it adds a lap in the car script so that fpA isn't static but it doesn't work.

Comment: ok so I tried doing OnTriggerEnter() and strangely it worked because earlier when I tried using it didn't work. But now the finish line doesn't work even tho' it is set to true. Look in the car script I posted above in the part where it collides with dpole code block. That part isn't working.

Comment: never mind fixed it. I had a child object which it needed to collide with. Thanks, you are da best :)